# Proof for multiplicative dominance of universal probability distribution

Tags: computability

I'm looking for the proof of the Leonid Levin theorem that states that the universal prior distribution function multiplicatively dominates all other functions of its type.
The original article is Levin 1974 but it is in Russian
Thanks

Comment: Should be in the Cover-Thomas book: http://coltech.vnu.edu.vn/~thainp/books/Wiley_-_2006_-_Elements_of_Information_Theory_2nd_Ed.pdf

Comment: [hope I'm not violating any copyright laws -- it's an "edu" link so I figure it must be ok]

Comment: @Aryeh, I think it might be better to link Google books's copy with the page (Chapter 14?).